# Understanding $k$-rotundity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-geometry

We know that the definitions of $k$-Uniform rotundity ($k$-UR) or locally $k$- uniform rotundity (L$k$-UR) act to find the volume in higher k-dimensional spaces by defining $V(x_1, ..., x_{k+1})$ (For the reference I have added the DOI of a paper on $k$-UR and L$k$-UR: https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100065701). But how can the slice in a Banach space be generalized in $k$-dimensional spaces? I mean, we can define a slice formed by the unit ball $B_X$ of a Banach space $X$ as:
$$ S(X, f, \delta) =\{ x \in B_X : f(x) \geq 1-\delta \}, f \in S_{X^*}.
$$
But how can we generalize this definition in $k$-dimensional spaces? I really appreciate any help you can provide.